# OPENGL lighting result comes out wrong

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

[my desired outcome(in red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH1Qc.png)
[image]

Hi, I'm trying to make my code in opengl c++ to produce this(with light coming from (1,1,1)), and it doesn't work and produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLDJE.png). Can anyone teach me why?

[image]

I thought it was about matrices calculation or lighting usage at first, but not so sure anymore.

light function

```
void init_light(void) {

    glLoadIdentity();

    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, ProjectionMat);
    ProjectionMatrix = glm::make_mat4(ProjectionMat);

    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ViewMat);
    ViewMatrix = glm::make_mat4(ViewMat);

    
    glm::mat4 InverseProjectionMatrix = glm::inverse(ProjectionMatrix);

    glm::mat4 InverseViewMatrix = glm::inverse(ViewMatrix);

    glm::mat4 M = glm::inverse(ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix);

    glm::mat4 Matr = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix;

    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    //glClearDepth(0.0);

    GLfloat ambient[] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 };
    GLfloat diffuse[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    //GLfloat position0[] = { 1., 1., 1., 0.0 };
    //GLfloat position1[] = { 1., 1., 1., 1.0 };

    GLfloat pos[] = { (GLfloat)(InverseViewMatrix * glm::make_vec4(position0))[0],
        (GLfloat)(InverseViewMatrix * glm::make_vec4(position0))[1],
        (GLfloat)(InverseViewMatrix * glm::make_vec4(position0))[2],
        (GLfloat)(InverseViewMatrix * glm::make_vec4(position0))[3] };

    GLfloat spot_direction[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specular);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, spot_direction);
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 1.0);
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 80.);
    //glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position0);
    //glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);
    //glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, 2.0);


    //glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, ambient);
    //glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse);
    //glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, position1);

    

    GLfloat mat_ambient[] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.0 };
    GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
    GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0 };
    //GLfloat mat_emissive[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    GLfloat mat_shininess[] = { 120.0 };


    

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, mat_ambient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
    //glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION, mat_emissive);


    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_AUTO_NORMAL);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

rendering scene

```
void renderScene(void) {


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glLoadIdentity();

    

    double ratio = window_size[0] * 1.0 / window_size[1];

    if (rotationbool == 1) {
        xRot = temp_xRot;
        yRot = temp_yRot;
    }

    
    

    glPopMatrix();
    gluPerspective(fovy, ratio, zNear + (zoom_factor)* ratio, zFar + (zoom_factor)* ratio);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, position1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glPopMatrix();
    glRotatef(xRot, 1.0, .0, .0);
    glRotatef(yRot, .0, 1.0, .0);
    glTranslatef(xTrans, yTrans, zTrans);
    glPushMatrix(); ...
}
```

main function

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    bool cad_draw = true;

    if (cad_draw) {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
    }

    double L_base[3] = { 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 };


    if (cad_draw) {
        finemost_limit[0] = L_base[0];
        finemost_limit[1] = L_base[1];
        finemost_limit[2] = L_base[2];

        window_params_init();

        //glDepthRange(1.0, 0.);

        

        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
        glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
        glutInitWindowSize(window_size[0], window_size[1]);
        glutCreateWindow("Interactive boundary design");
        glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, GLUT_ACTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION);

        
        
        //init_sfc();
        //init_light();
        
        // register callbacks
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
        //glDepthFunc(GL_GEQUAL);
        glDepthRange(1.0, 0.);  // left handed에서 right hanaded로 변경
        glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
        glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
        init_light();
        ///glutMouseWheelFunc(render_wheel);
        glutMouseFunc(mousePress);
        glutMotionFunc(mouseDrag);
        glutPassiveMotionFunc(passive_mouse);
        glutKeyboardFunc(simple_keyboard_binding);
        // enter GLUT event processing cycle
        glutMainLoop();

    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It seems that you've setup a point light source, which is very close to the sphere. What is `position0`? With commented out code (`position0 [] = {1., 1., 1., 0.0}`) it seems to work well.

Comment: It looks like you apply the perspective matrix to the `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix, which will completely screw up lighting (among other things). But you seriuosly should not be using deprectaed fixed-function GL which was replaced by shaders in 2004, and _removed_ from modern GL _over a decade ago_.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oh I forgot to erase the comment mark on that. postion0 is {1., 1., 1. ,0.0}

Comment: @derhass Are you referring to GLSL? I started out with just old codes and I won't go as far as this level, so I didn't wanted to go through fixing all of my stuffs unless it is totally necessary. If you say it is totally necessary, I'll seriously consider moving on to it. But if not, can you give me an alternative solution just using that?

Comment: Well, if it is strictly _necessary_ is a matter of opinion. The fixed-function is just a lie in this day and age, no real world GPU manufactured in the last 15 years really works that way. However, in terms of fixing your approach, I already told you that your use of the matrix stack is wrong. Not sure if it is the only issue in your code, but it is definitively a very serious one.